# Performance penalty of creating handlers on every render with react-hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions, react-hooks

I'm currently very amazed about the use cases of the new react [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) API and what you can possibly do with it.

A question that came up while experimenting was how expensive it is to always create a new handler function just to throw it away when using `useCallback`.

Considering this example:

```
const MyCounter = ({initial}) => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(initial);

    const increase = useCallback(() => setCount(count => count + 1), [setCount]);
    const decrease = useCallback(() => setCount(count => count > 0 ? count - 1 : 0), [setCount]);

    return (
        <div className="counter">
            <p>The count is {count}.</p>
            <button onClick={decrease} disabled={count === 0}> - </button>
            <button onClick={increase}> + </button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Although I'm wrapping the handler into a `useCallback` to avoid passing down a new handler every time it renders the inline arrow function still has to be created only to be thrown away in the majority of times.

Probably not a big deal if I only render a few components. But how big is the impact on performance if I do that 1000s of times? Is there a noticeable performance penalty? And what would be a way to avoid it? Probably a static handler factory that only gets called when a new handler has to be created?

Comment: OT: Just a quick question, If the whole point of Hooks is to prevent classes, how would ComponetDidMount, etc. fit in here.  Or would you still need to stick with classes for lifetime methods.?

Comment: @Keith There is a hook called [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) that can effectively replace lifetime methods.

Comment: Thanks, was just about to say, spotted that..  Might have to play with Hooks, never really felt right using `ComponetDidMount` etc, as a simple typo would stop event getting called.

Comment: `React relies on the order in which Hooks are called.`  Dam it!!!,  I do use conditional React rendering a fair bit, this will break.  And the workaround looks a hack.. :(

Comment: @Keith This is not a problem at all and does not differ to how class based stateful components work. You also wouldn't suddenly create a `this.state` and use it in the middle of the lifetime of a class component.  So the call to e.g. `useState` has to be unconditionally so react knows the component has state but using the state then can still be conditional.

Comment: Reading the docs, it seems it is a problem, and warns about it.   And if you want to add an effect like ComponentDidMount etc, you have to apply the hook anyway, and early terminate it.  All component have to be in the render pipeline so that hooks get re-assigned correctly. There is even an eslint plugin to prevent you doing this accidentally.  Maybe I'm missing something, but from my view on this, lets say we had this for the first render `<One><Two/></One><Three/>`, and all have hooks applied, and then the second render `<One/><Three/>`, The hooks for `Three` would be wrong.

Comment: @Keith No that is not the case. The hooks have to be called unconditionally and in the same order **inside of that component definition**. It does not matter in which order you render them. Or in other words: There is no global "order of called hooks" over the whole rendered tree. Just inside that component.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thanks for clarifying.  As reading the docs, and the example seemed to imply it was coming from some sort of render stream..  Maybe they could update the Doc's to clarify this, as re-reading it still doesn't seem obvious.. :)   I guess it's this part that's important -> `Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function`  (React function)..

Comment: @Keith The main thing to know is that react tracks in which component the hook was called and menorizes accordingly. And it knows which hook is what by the order of the hooks called in that component. But I already saw a lot of confusion about this as it is a little bit of black magic. But as soon as you understoid that it is great to use them. You can now write a lot of reusable code outside of components in custom hooks and use them avoiding e.g. the render prop hell.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm back to playing with them now.. :)   I think I've got the pro's of using it this way, I suppose it takes us more down the Composability route, and that's a good thing.. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The **[React FAQs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#are-hooks-slow-because-of-creating-functions-in-render)** provide an explanation to it

> **Are Hooks slow because of creating functions in render?**
>
> No. In modern browsers, the raw performance of closures compared to
>   classes doesn’t differ significantly except in extreme scenarios.
>
> In addition, consider that the design of Hooks is more efficient in a
>   couple ways:
>
> Hooks avoid a lot of the overhead that classes require, like the cost
>   of creating class instances and binding event handlers in the
>   constructor.
>
> Idiomatic code using Hooks doesn’t need the deep component tree
>   nesting that is prevalent in codebases that use higher-order
>   components, render props, and context. With smaller component trees,
>   React has less work to do.
>
> Traditionally, performance concerns around inline functions in React
>   have been related to how passing new callbacks on each render breaks
>   shouldComponentUpdate optimizations in child components. Hooks
>   approach this problem from three sides.

So overall benefits that hooks provide are much greater than the penalty of creating new functions

Moreover for functional components, you can optimize by making use of `useMemo` so that the components are re-rendering when there is not change in their props.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I read that too but it doesn't really answer my question. I'm not interested in the performance of using a closure but in the performance penalty of creating closures that aren't used anyways. If you look at the example you can see, that the inlined handlers will still be re-created on every render even if they aren't used which is a useless overhead. I would like to know how big that overhead is and if it is worth trying to avoid it.

Comment: @trixn, the inline arrow function are the function that are recreated everytime, but penalty for this is not more than the optimisation achieved by avoiding classes and HOCs hierarchy

Comment: Classes bind function / create arrow functions only once when created. How it could be slower or even equal to creating them on each render?

Comment: React developer notes does not make this the correct answer, nor true.

Comment: function component need more time to render because it create function on every render. See the [experiment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63353717/2822680).

Answer (score 13):

I did a simple test with the below example, which using 10k(and 100k) `usingCallback` hooks and re-rendering every 100ms. It seems that the number of `useCallback` could effect when it is really a lot. See the result below.

Function component with 10k hooks:

[image]

Each rendering took 8~12ms.

Function component with 100k hooks:

[image]

Each rendering took 25~80ms.

Class component with 10k methods:

[image]

Each rendering took 4~5ms.

Class component with 100k methods:
[image]

Each rendering took 4~6ms.

> I've tested with 1k example too. But the profile result looks almost same as the one with 10k.

So the penalty was noticeable in my browser when my component using 100k hooks while class component didn't show noticeable difference. So I guess It should be fine as long as you don't have a component using more than 10k hooks. The number probably depends on client's runtime resource though.

Test component code:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';

const callbackCount = 10000
const useCrazyCounter = () => {
  const callbacks = []
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  for (let i = 1; i < callbackCount + 1; i++) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    callbacks.push(useCallback(() => {
      setCount(prev => prev + i)
      // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, []))
  }
  return [count, ...callbacks]
}

const Counter = () => {
  const [count, plusOne] = useCrazyCounter()
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(plusOne, 100)
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer)
    }}
  , [])
  return <div><div>{count}</div><div><button onClick={plusOne}>Plus One</button></div></div>
}

class ClassCounter extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    }
    for (let i = 1; i < callbackCount; i++) {
      this['plus'+i] = () => {
        this.setState(prev => ({
          count: prev.count + i
        }))
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.plus1()
    }, 100)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer)
  }

  render () {
    return <div><div>{this.state.count}</div><div><button onClick={this.plus1}>Plus One</button></div></div>
  }

}

const App = () => {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Counter/>
      {/* <ClassCounter/> */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 5):

**But how big is the impact on performance if I do that 1000s of times? Is there a noticeable performance penalty?**

It depends on the app. If you're just simply rendering 1000 rows of counters, it's probably ok, as seen by the code snippet below. Note that if you are just modifying the state of an individual `<Counter />`, only that counter is re-rendered, the other 999 counters are not affected.

But I think you're concerned over irrelevant things here. In real world apps, there is unlikely to have 1000 list elements being rendered. If your app has to render 1000 items, there's probably something wrong with the way you designed your app.

1. You should not be rendering 1000 items in the DOM. That's usually bad from a performance and UX perspective, with or without modern JavaScript frameworks. You could use windowing techniques and only render items that you see on the screen, the other off-screen items can be in memory.
2. Implement `shouldComponentUpdate` (or `useMemo`) so that the other items do not get re-rendered should a top level component have to re-render.
3. By using functions, you avoid the overhead of classes and some other class-related stuff that goes on under the hood which you don't know of because React does it for you automatically. You lose some performance because of calling some hooks in functions, but you gain some performance elsewhere also.
4. Lastly, note that you are calling the `useXXX` hooks and not executing the callback functions you passed into the hooks. I'm sure the React team has done a good job in making hooks invocation lightweight calling hooks shouldn't be too expensive.

**And what would be a way to avoid it?**

I doubt there would be a real world scenario where you will need to create stateful items a thousand times. But if you really have to, it would be better to lift the state up into a parent component and pass in the value and increment/decrement callback as a prop into each item. That way, your individual items don't have to create state modifier callbacks and can simply use the callback prop from its parent. Also, stateless child components make it easier to implement the various well-known perf optimizations.

Lastly, I would like to reiterate that you should not be worried about this problem because you should be trying to avoid landing yourself into such a situation instead of dealing with it, be leveraging on techniques like windowing and pagination - only loading the data that you need to show on the current page.

```js
const Counter = ({ initial }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(initial);

  const increase = React.useCallback(() => setCount(count => count + 1), [setCount]);
  const decrease = React.useCallback(
    () => setCount(count => (count > 0 ? count - 1 : 0)),
    [setCount]
  );

  return (
    <div className="counter">
      <p>The count is {count}.</p>
      <button onClick={decrease} disabled={count === 0}>
        -
      </button>
      <button onClick={increase}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(1000);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Counters: {count}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => {
        setCount(count + 1);
      }}>Add Counter</button>
      <hr/>
      {(() => {
        const items = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          items.push(<Counter key={i} initial={i} />);
        }
        return items;
      })()}
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <App />
  </div>,
  document.querySelector("#app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

One way could be **memoizing the callbacks** to prevent the unnecessary updates of child components.
you can read more about this [here](https://medium.com/@samanmhd/boost-performance-of-functional-react-components-with-memoized-callbacks-441343a237b7).

Also, I create an npm package [useMemoizedCallback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-memoized-callback) which I hope helps anyone looking for a solution to increase performance.

Comment: I am aware that memorizing callbacks is the solution to prevent unnecessary re-rerenders of children. I already used that in my example in the question. But as the callbacks are defined as closures the functions themself will still have to be created on every render even though they aren't used. My question was about the performance impact of that. Does you package provide any advantage to `useCallback` with an empty dependency list?

Comment: No, my package best fitted for callbacks that dependent on more than one state variable. it brings maximum performance which will be equal to useCallback without dependency but useCallback with no dependency is not possible all the time.

Answer (score -2):

You are right, in large applications this can lead to performance issues. Binding the handler before you pass it to the component avoids that the child component might does an extra re-rendering.

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>click me!</button>
<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>click me!</button>
```

Both are equivalent. The e argument representing the React event, while with an arrow function, we have to pass it explicitly, with bind any arguments are automatically forwarded.

Comment: I am aware of that and `useCallback` effectively avoids that. My question is slightly different. If you look at the example you can see that a new inline function is created on every render. `useCallback` will just not use it and return the memorized callback avoiding passing a new handler down. But still since it is inlined the function has to be "created". Will just get thrown away in many cases.

Comment: By the way, both your examples suffer from the same problem that a new function will be passed on every render making the child re-render. If you want to avoid that you must bind handlers once in the constructor. Binding them inline will create a new function. Also the first example can be simplified to `<button onClick={this.handleClick}>click me!</button>`. The arrow function doesn't add anything here.
`

Comment: @trixn *"The arrow function doesn't add anything here"*, actually it does. It preserves `this`, which is otherwise lost in the function. This is exactly what `.bind()` does.

Comment: @Qtax I am aware of that. But as this questions discusses functional components I don't see any point in binding the function to `this`. This would only make sense with class based components to access other properties bound to the component instance.

Comment: @trixn `this.` in `onClick={this.handleClick}` indicates that it's a class component tho.

Comment: @Qtax The question was about hooks which can exclusively be used in functional components. The answer you are commenting on is irrelevant to my question because it talks about handlers in class based components. I am aware of what `bind()` does and as it is used in this example it will recreate the handler on every render which is what you want to avoid. If you want to bind your handlers to `this` in a class based component you should do that in the constructor. The answer just makes no sense.