# Is there any difference between rendering a functional component with and without hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Just tried some react-hooks and got some questions.

Consider this functional component with react-hooks:

```
const Counter = (props) => {
  console.log("Counter component");

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleIncrease = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }

  const handleDecrease = () => {
    setCount(count - 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleIncrease}>+</button>
      <button onClick={handleDecrease}>-</button>
      <p>{count}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

It logged everytime I clicked the "+" or "-".

Does it means that every handlers inside this component(or say, function) are redeclared and reassigned to a variable? If it did, won't it cause some performance issues?

To me the functional component with hooks seems like a huge render method of a classical component like this:

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
  }

  render() {
    const handleIncrease = () => {
      this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
    }

    const handleDecrease = () => {
      this.setState({ count: this.state.count - 1 });
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleIncrease}>+</button>
        <button onClick={handleDecrease}>-</button>
        <p>{count}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

which I think nobody will do this.

Did I have misunderstandings of the React's render mechanism or it's just not the best practice when using the functional component with react-hooks?

Comment: have you read the docs? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: When a prop or state changes, the whole function is rerun again, as you suspect.

Comment: Ahh.. thanks! I did miss the useCallback and the useMemo. But although it prevents unnecessary rerenderings of child components, React still executes the “useCallback(...)” hooks every time it rerender the functional component right? I don’t know if it will cause some performance issues or it’s just nothing compared to the cost of using the classical component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although in functional components functions are recreated on every render, the performance cost of it much less compared to the benefits.

You can refer this post for more details: [Performance penalty of creating handlers on every render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53335950/performance-penalty-of-creating-handlers-on-every-render/53336060#53336060)

However you can still optimise so that functions are not recreated on every render using `useCallback` or `useReducer(depending on whether your updates are complex or not)`

```
const Counter = (props) => {
  console.log("Counter component");

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleIncrease = useCallback(() => {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
  }, [])

  const handleDecrease = useCallback(() => {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleIncrease}>+</button>
      <button onClick={handleDecrease}>-</button>
      <p>{count}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

In the above example the functions are re-created only on the initial render and using the state update callback we can update the state and avoid closure issues

Comment: Thanks a lot! That post totally answers my question.

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)