# Declare function inside function body or outside with passing the parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have a function, which will run multiple times - outside function for now -  (for example with react, so it can define more clear what I'm asking about). If we define the function inside the outside function body, we can take advantage of closure, so we'll have access to the outside function's scope.

In the second scenario, we define the function independently, so outside the function body. This way we won't have access to the outside function's scope, so we'll have to pass what we need as parameters.

The important question is: is there any significant performance difference between declaring the function outside, or declaring it inside a function which will get called multiple times? As other words, does a function declaration inside an outer function's body will take time every time the outer function runs?

See example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const outerOnChange = ({ target: { value } }, setValue) => setValue(value);

const Input = () => {

  const [ value, setValue ] = useState("");

  const innerOnChange = ({ target: { value: newValue } }) => setValue(newValue);

  const onChange = e => {
    outerOnChange(e, setValue);
    innerOnChange(e);
  };

  return <input onChange={onChange} value={value} />;
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance penalty of creating handlers on every render with react-hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53335950/performance-penalty-of-creating-handlers-on-every-render-with-react-hooks/53336060#53336060)

Comment: This question is not exactly a duplicate of the question mentioned, the answer mentioned in that question explains the performance difference between react without hooks and react with hooks. In this question he used hooks to explain the question, but this question is about performance difference between a function declared inside closure vs function declared outside a closure

Comment: It doesn't really answer my question. The question isn't React related, I could demonstrate it with an event listener which runs every time a mouse move happens for example.

Comment: When you declare a function inside a closure, a new instance of the function is created every time the outer function is executed, if any of the variables that references this inner function is kept alive outside the closure, then multiple instances of the function will be kept alive in the memory. But if none of them are kept alive the inner function will be destroyed immediately. As per the case of declaring it outside the closure, there will only be one instance of the function but it will always be kept alive as long as the closure uses it.

Comment: So its your decision, use the one that is perfect for your use case