# Function inside functional component in React hooks - Performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Need suggestion on having function within a functional component in react `Hooks`.

As far as I researched, many are saying it is bad practice
because it creates nested/inner function every time we call re-render.
After doing some analysis,

I found we can use `onClick={handleClick.bind(null, props)}` on the element and place the function outside the functional component.

Example:

```
const HelloWorld = () => {
  function handleClick = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  return() {
    <>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleClick}/>
    </>
  }
}
```

Please advise if there is any alternative way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your example is showing. Either way you're creating a new function per render. Plus the example function seems wrong.

Comment: How do we avoid creating new function per render in functional component ?

Comment: [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

Comment: `useCallback` which will be (roughly) a no-op if the function or its dependencies hasn't changed.

Answer (score 39):

## Don't worry about it

Don't worry about creating new functions on each render. Only in edge cases does that impede your performance.
Setting `onClick` handlers are not one of those, so just create a new function on each render.

However, when you need to make sure you use the same function every time, you can use [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

## Why not use `useCallback` for `onClick`

Here is a reason why you shouldn't bother with `useCallback` for `onClick` handlers (and most other event handlers).

Consider the following code snippets, one without useCallback:

```js
function Comp(props) {
  return <button onClick={() => console.log("clicked", props.foo)}>Text</Button>
}
```

and one with useCallback:

```js
function Comp(props) {
  const onClick = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("clicked", props.foo)
  }, [props.foo])

  return <button onClick={onClick}>Text</Button>
}
```

The only difference in the latter is that React doen's have
to change the `onClick` on your button if `props.foo` remains the same.
**Changing the callback is a very cheap operation**, and it's not at all
worth complicating your code for the theoretical performance improvement it gives.

Also, it's worth noting that **a new function is still created on every render**
even when you use `useCallback`, but `useCallback` will return the old one
as long as the dependencies passed as the second argument are unchanged.

## Why ever use `useCallback`

The point of using `useCallback` is that if you compare two functions with reference
equality, `fn === fn2` is true only if `fn` and `fn2` point to the same function in memory.
It doesn't matter if the functions *do* the same.

Thus, if you have memoisation or otherwise only run code when the function changes,
it can be useful to use `useCallback` to use the same function again.

As an example, React hooks compare old and new dependencies, [probably](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update) using [Object.is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Description).

Another example is [React.PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent), which will only re-render when props or state have changed. This can be useful for components that use a lot of resources to render. Passing e.g. a new `onClick` to a PureComponent on each render will cause it to re-render every time.

Comment: +1 for "Also, it's worth noting that a new function is still created on every render even when you use useCallback"

Comment: "Also, it's worth noting that a new function is still created on every render even when you use useCallback". Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: It probably is, though I couldn't find it right now, @chetan. To explain in my own words: To pass the function to `useCallback`, it must be created. This happens on every render. React keeps track of which component instance is calling `useCallback` (or any hook), and returns the right (old or new) function based on the deps.

Comment: Are you sure it happens on every render? Yes, to pass the function to useCallback it must be created the first time. But maybe on subsequent renders, useCallback doesn't redefine the function at all and uses the cached definition. The react docs mention that "useCallback(fn, deps) is equivalent to useMemo(() => fn, deps)". This could mean that a cached definition of fn is returned. There are also articles like [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usecallback-hook) that suggest the function is not redefined. I think we can be sure only if it is documented or if we have read the source code.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The code in the function component is run on every time it is called (which happens when it's rendered), including code that creates functions passed to `useCallback`. There is no way to get around this in JavaScript as a language – at least not as it is today. (The article you link to is indeed misleading when it states that "functions aren't re-initialized for every re-render of a component". They _are_ recreated, but memoized so you get the previous function unless deps have changed.)

Comment: Yes, there is no denying that code in the function component and the useCallback function is run everytime. The question is, does each run of useCallback define a new function? It is not difficult to check the dependency array and not redefine the function at all if that array hasn't changed. And what about the point I raised about the docs - "useCallback(fn, deps) is equivalent to useMemo(() => fn, deps)". This also suggests that fn is not redefined because "() => fn" isn't run at all if deps hasn't changed. This line from the docs favours that article's argument more than your argument.

Comment: I don't think comments are the right place to properly explain this. I'll try to make a Q/A to explain it at some point.

Comment: "Also, it's worth noting that a new function is still created on every render even when you use useCallback" this is not correct. React uses indexes under the hood to label each hook call (that's why the rules of hooks exist). So as long as the dependency array is the same, the same function will be returned. so no new function is created.

Comment: @pouria, the same function is **returned**  unless the deps change, but a new function is still **created** on every render. (The new function is passed into `useCallback`, and `useCallback` decides whether to return the new or the old one, that's all. React cannot interpolate the code to stop the unused function from being created in the first place.)

Answer (score 14):

> many are saying it is bad practice because it creates nested/inner function every time we call re-render

No, inner functions / closures are so common, there is no problem with them. The engine can heavily optimize those.

The point here is that *you pass the function as a prop to the child component*. And as the function was "recreated", it does not equal the previous function passed, annd thus *the child does rerender* (and that's whats bad for performance).

You can resolve that with `useCallback`, which memoizes the function reference.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Interesting question, me and my coleagues had some worries about this, so I did a test.

I have created 1 Component with Hooks and 1 Component with Class, put some functions there and then render it 1000x times.

The Component with Class looks like this:

```
export class ComponentClass extends React.PureComponent {
  click1 = () => {
    return console.log("just a log");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <span onClick={this.click1}>1</span>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

The Component with Hooks looks like this:

```
export const ComponentHook = React.memo((props) => {
  const click1 = () => {
    return console.log("just a log");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <span onClick={click1}>1</span>
    </>
  );
});
```

I have added more click handlers to the components and then rendered them some 1000s times, the Class is faster as it does not define the functions each render, if you increase the number of functions defined, then the difference will be bigger:

Here it is a codesandbox so you can test the performance Class vs Hooks : https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-vs-class-forked-erdpb

Comment: Here, fixed it for you with useCallback ;) https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-vs-class-with-usecallback-fuyrx2?file=/src/ComponentHook.js
Now hooks version is faster.

Answer (score 8):

### `useCallback`

You can use `useCallback` feature :

```
const HelloWorld = ({ dispatch }) => {
  const handleClick = useCallback((event) => {
    dispatch(() => {console.log(event.target.value)});
  })

  return() {
    <>
        <input type="name" onChange={handleClick}/>
    </>
  }
}
```

> `useCallback` will return a memoized version of the callback that only
> changes if one of the dependencies has changed. This is useful when
> passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference
> equality to prevent unnecessary renders (e.g. shouldComponentUpdate).

For further details visit react documentation reference: [React useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

---

### Old Solution

First solution:
To pass the your `handleClick` function to your functional component.

```
const HelloWorld = (props) => {

  return() {
    <>
        <input type="name" onChange={props.handleClick}/>
    </>
  }
}
```

Second solution:
To define your function outside of your functional component.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @tibbus 's benchmark, I made this one that tests the perfomance using or not the useCallback hook. After several executions, it seams that the use of useCallback can be very important for high frequency rendering.

**Execution 1**

[image]

**Execution 2**

[image]

**Execution 3**

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/usecallback-vs-raw-definition-xke9v?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

As per  [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) (ending part),

> The problem with latter syntax is that a different callback is created
>   each time the `LoggingButton` renders. In most cases, this is fine.
>   However, if this callback is passed as a prop to lower components,
>   those components might do an extra re-rendering. We generally
>   recommend binding in the constructor or using the class fields syntax,
>   to avoid this sort of performance problem.

Class field syntax:

```
class LoggingButton extends React.Component {
  // This syntax ensures `this` is bound within handleClick.
  // Warning: this is *experimental* syntax.
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log('this is:', this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Click me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

arrow function in the callback syntax:

```
class LoggingButton extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
    console.log('this is:', this);
  }

  render() {
    // This syntax ensures `this` is bound within handleClick
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
        Click me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would honestly just use a class component in these cases. I'm aware of premature optimization, but creating a new function each time does just seem like extravagant wastefulness without much of a maintainability upside. tibbus has demonstrated the perf hit, and inline functions are arguably less readable than class methods. All you're losing out is the slick feeling of writing a functional component.

Answer (score 0):

**Just `useCallback`**

Why would you need to define a function inside a component and not anywhere else? Because you either have to pass it to another child compononent, or you have to use it in an effect, memo, or another callback. For any of those cases if you dont wrap your function in useCallback you will be passing a new function and causing the component to rerender, the memo to re-run, the effect  to re-run, or the callback to re-define.

You can never avoid the performance hit of redefining the function itself, but you can avoid the performance hit of performing any computation that has that function as a dependency to know if it has to run or not (be it a component or hook).

So... just wrap every function in your component in `useCallback` and forget about it, never seen a single in case in which this would cause any harm. If you can define the function outside the component, thats always better.