# React Component Re-render

Tags: reactjs

What happens to a function when a component re-renders in react? Is it recreated everytime?

```
export default function App() {
  console.log("rendered");
  const [isOpen, setisOpen] = useState(false);
  function handleClick() {
    setisOpen(true);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
      {isOpen && <div>Secret is opened.</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Why does this component renders 3 times?

Comment: on every render `handleClick` will be re-created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57289811/function-inside-functional-component-in-react-hooks-performance

Answer (score 0):

On every render of the parent function it's child function gets created in order to prevent this you can use react hook called useCallBack

```
    import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
    export default function App() {
       console.log("rendered");
       const [isOpen, setisOpen] = useState(false);
       const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
         setisOpen(true);
       }, []);

      return (
        <div className="App">
          <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
          {isOpen && <div>Secret is opened.</div>}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

here [] means this child function will be created once when parent function rendered

Comment: Hey Anku. Thanks for the response. I don't see the use of Callback here. Even if we do that, we are still getting 3 renders.

Comment: If you are calling this App component in some other component as child component then you need to use React.memo() hook to prevent re rendering re rendering will only occur when any props passed to this App component will change read this article you will get the idea https://dmitripavlutin.com/use-react-memo-wisely/